# How can I aggregate all instance of a deeply nested attribute in Ruby on Rails and ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, nested

I have the following setup:
A Mealplan has multiple Days. A Day has multiple Meals and a Meal has multiple Recipes.

I want to list for a Mealplan all the recipes that belong to it. For the time being, I implemented a very ugly triple for loop that does the trick. However, it is very slow and highly inefficient.

```
    def generate
    mealplan = self.mealplan
    self.ingredients = []
    for day in mealplan.days
        for meal in day.meals
            for recipe in meal.recipes
                self.ingredients << recipe.ingredients
            end
        end
    end
    self.save

    return nil
end
```

Does ActiveRecord propose a more elegant and efficient solution for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can write your associations like this

```
 class Mealplan
   has_many :days 
   has_many :meals, through: :days 
   has_many :ingredients, through: :meals
```

and then you can just retrieve the `ingredients` for a mealplan using `mealplan.ingredients`.

Now this could conflict with your fields `ingredients` you are trying to set, which is a calculated field? Or is it some kind of cache-field? Or is this an association on the level of `Mealplan`?

I am assuming that your associations would look like

```
class Meal 
  has_many :meal_ingredients
  has_many :ingredients, through: :meal_ingredients
```

But since a meal is linked to a meal-plan, we can go from from mealplan to their ingredients pretty easy. If you want to make it even simpler/quicker, you could define your `MealIngredient` as follows

```
class MealIngredient 
  belongs_to :meal 
  belongs_to :mealplan 
  belongs_to :ingredient
```

I am assuming a `MealIngredient` also contains quantities, so maybe that is why you want a calculated/cached report of ingredients linked to but my first approach would be to just fetch all the ingredients linked to a mealplan via all the meals (as shown) and calculate totals only when needed (when you need to show them), and keep the report dynamic.

I am sorry if this answer has diverged a bit too much from the original question.

Comment: This is actually exactly what I needed. I had the right idea but the wrong execution.
I created a "Grocery List" model that would like all the ingredients through the generate function above.
I just deleted this function and changed the associations as suggested. Works like a charm!
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

As the question mentions about the poor performance of the current strategy. This caused by a lot of SQLs are generated when the method is called.

Assume the association has been setup as [@nathanvda's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59565562/1659807) has mentioned, another way to implement this function is to use the `join` method.

```rb
Ingredient.joins(meal: { days: :meal_plan }).where(meal_plans: { id: self.id })
```